# How many times a string is used in a vector

Tags: c#

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Here you can write the name as many as you want,
and if u wanna end up just write No!");

Console.WriteLine("\n");
Console.WriteLine("Start writing a name:");


string[] namnArray = new string[200];
for (int i = 0; i < namnArray.Length; i++)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
    namnArray[i] = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    Console.Write("Do u wanna write another one?  ");

    if (namnArray[i] == "No")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
        Console.WriteLine("write a name of your choice:");
        
        //Here i wanna know how many times a names used as the user wrote up there!
        //but dont know how to do it, if you wanna help me will be thankful!
    }
}
```

I tried to make a new string variable as

```
string youChoice = Console.ReadLine();
```

and then I don't know how to go further!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a fixed size array for this. You're almost certainly better off using `List<string>` instead.

```
var namnList = new List<string>();
string enteredNamn;
do {
    ...
    enteredNamn = Console.ReadLine();
    namnList.Add(enteredNamn);

} while (enteredNamn != "No");
```

Then you can use the `List<>.Count()` to count all matches.

```
var chosenNamn = Console.ReadLine();
var count = namnList.Count(x => x == chosenNamn);
```

***Disclaimer - code for illustrative purposes only, I make no guarantee that this will even compile***

Answer (score 0):

Console.WriteLine("Here you can write the name as many as you want, and if u wanna end up just write No!");

```
  Console.WriteLine("\n");
  Console.WriteLine("Start writing a name:");
  string[] namnArray = new string[200];
 
  for (int i = 0; i < namnArray.Length; i++)
  {
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
    namnArray[i] = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    Console.Write("Do u wanna write another one?  ");

    if (namnArray[i] == "No")
    {
      Console.WriteLine("\n");
      Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
      Console.WriteLine("write a name of your choice:");
      var names = string.Join("", namnArray);
      var input = Console.ReadLine();
      var count = Regex.Matches(names, input).Count;
      Console.WriteLine("The number of ocurance is " + count);

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

General Kenobi. You are a bold one.

You can use [Array.FindAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.findall?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_Array_FindAll__1___0___System_Predicate___0__):

```
var number = Array.FindAll(namnArray, x => x == name ).Count();
```

The FindAll

> Retrieves all the elements that match the conditions defined by the specified predicate.

For more info about FindAll and example of use follow the [link to the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.findall?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_Array_FindAll__1___0___System_Predicate___0__).